# IPA size more than expected

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ipa

I am developing an app for ios. The code comprising all the imageassets and libraries is of 11.2 MB. But when I create the ipa, it is of 19 MB. The size is increasing instead of compressing the code.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: My be you build in the Debug mode?

Comment: Please check This link :- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1779/_index.html and http://www.indiepinion.com/steffenj/how-to-calculate-the-size-of-an-iphone-app-after-approval/